# Как преобразовать тип String в Int?

Tags: java, строки, int

Нужно, чтобы условие проверяло два числа из массива, и если хотя бы одно из двух чисел будет с плавающей точкой, выбрасывалось исключение.
Но при срабатывании когда `isDouble` приравнивает число, введенное пользователем, проводит `try` и сравнивает число, допустим, 5 и 5-ку, преобразованную в тип `Double`, они приравниваются и исключение всегда выбрасывается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.

```java
if (isDouble(h[0]) || isDouble(h[1])) {
    throw new Exception("Вводите только целые числа!");
}
```

```java
public static boolean isDouble(String s) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну собственно 5 является вполне допустимым числом с плавающей точкой, так что всё правильно

Comment: А если пользователь введёт не число вообще, то, получается, вас это никак не смущает?

Comment: У меня есть определенная задача, проверочная типо. Есть список с тасками что сделать надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, зачем проверять, что строка содержит число типа `double`, если в условии требуется проверить, чтобы это число было **целым**, то есть такая строка по определению не может содержать никакие символы кроме цифр и опционально знака `-` или `+`.
Строки, содержащие десятичную точку, *уже* не являются целыми, даже если их дробная часть нулевая ("5.000") или отсутствует ("3.").

При этом не всякая строка, содержащая только *десятичные* цифры, может быть преобразована в целое число, которое поместится в диапазон значений типа `int`: [-2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup> - 1] или даже `long` [-2<sup>63</sup>, 2<sup>63</sup> - 1].

Поэтому в наиболее общем случае следует использовать регулярное выражение, чтобы проверять целые числа произвольной длины (ограниченные максимально допустимой длиной строки)

```java
// целое число (со знаком или без) любой длины
public static boolean isDecimalInteger(String s) {
    return s != null && s.matches("[+-]?\\d+"); // \d - десятичные цифры
}
```

Если же известно, что строка содержит целые числа из ограниченного диапазона типа `int`, можно воспользоваться обычным методом `Integer::parseInt`, который обеспечит проверку, что в строке записано 32-битное *знаковое* целое (в десятичной системе).

```java
// целое знаковое число
public static boolean isSignedInt(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Такой метод вернёт `false` для `"3000000000"`.

Также есть возможность "расширить" диапазон на 1 бит, проверяя беззнаковое число при помощи `Integer::parseUnsignedInt`, тогда в него попадут числа [0, 2<sup>32</sup> - 1], т.е. `"3000000000"` считается целым, а `"-1"` - уже нет.

```java
public static boolean isUnsignedInt(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Теперь, определив методы для проверки целых чисел, следует переписать условие для выбрасывания исключения в исходном коде, с использованием *нужного* метода проверки, например:

```java
// ...
if (!isSignedInt(h[0]) || !isSignedInt(h[1])) {
    throw new Exception("Вводите только целые числа!");
}
```